# Visual Studio debugger instance not found when launching debugger from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2022

I'm developing a C# application (let's call it `app A`) that, at a certain point, launches another C# application (let's call it `app B`) by invoking `Process.Start(...)`.
Both apps are part of the same Visual Studio solution (I'm using Visual Studio 2022).

When debugging, I launch `app A` with the Visual Studio debugger, and that works without issues. However, I also need to debug `app B` whenever `app A` launches it.

In order to do this, since `app B` is not launched from Visual Studio and thus doesn't attach to the debugger automatically, I added this code to the top of its `main()` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
#if DEBUG
    Debugger.Launch();
#endif

//... rest of the main()
}
```

And here is when I have an annoying issue. This is what I see when that line of code executes:

[image]

As you can see, it is not detecting the currently running instance of Visual Studio, it only gives me the option to launch a new one. If I do that the debugger attaches, however the new instance doesn't have the solution open, so it doesn't have the proper source code loaded, providing a much worse debugging experience (and not to mention the fact that it wastes time because a whole new instance of VS needs to open).

I want to know why this happens, because I've seen in online tutorials that you can attach to a running instance of Visual Studio which should appear in the list, so why is mine not showing up?

Note: I've read around that this tends to happen if you've launched VS or your app as administrator, however this is not the case, everything is running non-elevated here.

What am I missing?

Comment: Start the app A exe-file, then in Visual Studio choose Debug/Attach to process and attach app B to the app A process.

Comment: @PalleDue: thanks for the idea, but if I'm doing it "manually" like you suggest it's easier/faster to just debug app A normally and then manually do debug -> attach to process in VS when I need to debug app B.

Comment: As you're running the app via `Process.Start` then I think you have to attach to the process.

Comment: @stuartd: I know, what I'm asking is why isn't my already open instance of visual studio detected when doing Debugger.Launch() in code and instead I have to launch a new one every tome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I do that the debugger attaches, however the new instance doesn't have the solution open, so it doesn't have the proper source code loaded.

I followed below steps and found that it can have the `app B` open and loads the source code successfully when i selected a new instance in Just-In-Time Debugger window.

1.Invoke app B in app A.

```
Process.Start(@"path\app B.exe");
```

2 Select a new instance to debug app B and it opens app B solution like this.
[image]

> because I've seen in online tutorials that you can attach to a running instance of Visual Studio which should appear in the list.

From my understanding, Just-In-Time Debugger can detect running instance of visual studio  when you open `app b` in another VS instance.

[image]

This [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022#BKMK_Attach_to_a_running_process) notes you can attach to running processes with the Visual Studio debugger.

If there is any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Well the two apps are part of the same solution... so what you're saying is that I should have two solution open in two different instances of VS, one to debug app A and one to debug app B? It's not ideal but better than launching a new instance every time I guess... I'll accept your answer later if nobody comes up with a better solution